# vim combine with tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I want to ask about vim+ tmux. I open two file with vim in two tmux pane. How can I copy code from vim in first pane to second pane. I used mode copy of tmux, but It had a number line and created a new line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is **How to copy text from one vim window (in one tmux pane) to another vim window (in another tmux pane)** then It's a matter of `vim-clipboard`.

In that case, on your terminal type `vim --version | grep clipboard` then if output has something like this

```
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
```

Notice the `+clipboard` means, your vim has clipboard capabilities.

And you can simply copy code by doing this,

**Visual Mode**

1. Visually select the text you need to copy.
2. On your keyboard type `"+yy` to "yank" text.

**Normal Mode**

3. By using numbers you can say `12"+y`
4. Or you can say `"+yy` to yank the current line.

**Pasting**

After you have copied text from one vim window, you can then navigate to the second one and go to **INSERT mode** then type `Ctrl r +` *Control + r + plus sign* which pastes text from vim `:REG` *Type that and see everything stored in them which you can actually replace the `plus sign` in that code*.

If however you have something like `-clipboard` this means you don't have clipboard capabilities in your vim.

Easiest way is to install `vim-nox` which has lots of capabilities including clipboard. Or install `gvim` which will add your terminal vim those capabilities.

While pasting it's important to `:set paste` before pasting and then `:set nopaste` after pasting to reserve some formatting from the clipboard text into vim.

**Regarding copying with tmux**

Well, tmux will treat the whole of your vim as a board and it will just copy everything *even the status bar* the correct way to copy stuffs from vim is using **vim's clipboard capabilities** and the correct way to copy stuffs from your terminal is using `tmux & xclip`.

[Here is more about vim clipboard](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard)